# Retrieve query as IQueryable using MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, iqueryable

I'm updating an old project that implemented the database layer as interfaces so it's easier to add a new database option. I'm currently trying to add MongoDB implementation to it and I've ran into some trouble.

The project has an interface called `IDataQuery` which derives from the the `LINQ.IQueryable` interface:

```
public interface IDataQuery<out T> : IQueryable<T>
{
}
```

It also has an interfac called `IDataSession` which has a `Query` method that returns this type of `IDataQuery`:

```
public interface IDataSession : IDisposable
{
    IDataQuery<T> Query<T>() where T : class, IDataEntity;
}
```

I've created a class called `MongoDataSession` which derives from this interface and implements the `Query` method like so:

```
public class MongoDataSession : IDataSession
{
    private IMongoDatabase m_database;

    public MongoDataSession(IMongoDatabase database)
    {
        m_database = database;
    }

    public IDataQuery<T> Query<T>() where T : class, IDataEntity
    {
        var collection = m_database.GetCollection<T>("test");

        return collection.AsQueryable<T>();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // TODO.
    }
}
```

However, the MongoDB `AsQueryable` method returns the result as `IMongoQueryable`. I tried to cast it to `IDataQuery<T>` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I created a wrapper around `IDataQuery` and casted to that.